# Seed and Private Key

Tags: security, seed

I use, for example, a Phantom, and I created 10 wallets by seed phase.
Then I shared the private key (via *export private key*) of one of the wallets.
Can anyone access the rest of the wallets based on a private key?
Seed phrase remained a secret.

Answer (score 1):

So seed phase can extract private key, and private key can extract public key. I highly doubt they might be able to use the wallet. But to be on the safer side make sure to never share your private key